# xamarin forms dependent dropdown using local json data and multiple item selection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

in my xamarin forms application registration part  i need to fill profession and expertise field from a local json.The profession field is a dropdown and then expertise is also a dropdown and subpart of profession.From expertise field i need to select minimum one and maximum 3 options.

ProfessionalRegistrationPage.xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ProfessionalRegistrationPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<Profession> professions { get; set; }

    public List<Profession> expertises { get; set; }

    public ProfessionalRegistrationPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        professions = GetJsonDataProfession();

        BindingContext = this;

        professionPicker.ItemsSource = professions;
        professionPicker.SelectedItem = professions[0];
    }

    private List<Profession> GetJsonDataProfession()
    {
        string jsonFileName = "profession.json";
        ProfessionList ObjProfessionList = new ProfessionList();

        var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{ assembly.GetName().Name}.{ jsonFileName}");

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            ObjProfessionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfessionList>(jsonString);
        }

        return ObjProfessionList.professions;
    }

    private void professionPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker picker = (Picker)sender;

        int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex != -1)
        {
            expertises = professions[selectedIndex].expertises;
            expertisePicker.ItemsSource = expertises;
            expertisePicker.SelectedItem = expertises[0];
        }
    }
}


public partial class ProfessionList
{
    [JsonProperty("professions")]
    public List<Profession> professions { get; set; }
}


public partial class Profession
{
    [JsonProperty("expertises")]
    public List<Profession> expertises { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("professionname")]
    public string ProfessionName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expertisename")]
    public string ExpertiseName { get; set; }
}
```

ProfessionalRegistrationPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Text="Profession" 
           TextColor="{StaticResource BackgroundGradientStart}">
    </Label>
    
      <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
             BorderColor="{StaticResource BackgroundGradientStart}" 
             Padding="0"  
             Margin="10" 
             CornerRadius="15" 
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <Picker   
            x:Name="professionPicker"
            SelectedIndexChanged="professionPicker_SelectedIndexChanged"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ProfessionName}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding profession}"    
            TextColor="{StaticResource White}"/>
      </Frame>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Text="Expertise"  
           TextColor="{StaticResource BackgroundGradientStart}">
    </Label>
    <Frame 
        BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
        BorderColor="{StaticResource BackgroundGradientStart}" 
        Padding="0"  
         Margin="10" 
         CornerRadius="15" 
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        
         <Picker  x:Name="expertisePicker"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ExpertiseName}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding profession}"  
                TextColor="{StaticResource White}"/>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

```
profession.json

{
"professions": [
{
"professionname": "Doctor",
"expertises": [
{
"expertisename": "Pediatric"
},
{
"expertisename": "Ortho"
}
]
},
 {
"professionname": "Engineer",
"expertises": [
{
 "expertisename": "Software"
},
{
 "expertisename": "Civil"
}
]
 }
]
}
```

i used picker here.but picker doesnot support more than one item selection.
otherwise its works perfectly.

i think i need to place a popup and in pop up page i need to fix a listview and checkbox. but i dont now how to do that. I am new to xamarin.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: First, please format your post so that it is readable.  Second, it appears that you are already deserializing your json data into C# objects and assigning them to your Picker's ItemSource.  This is correct - so where exactly are you stuck?  What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: hi @jason i need to select minimum one and maximum 3 items from the expertise dropdown .but here i used picker which doesnot support more than one item selection.

Comment: use a CollectionView instead